Weak solutions of heat equation in Brezis' book
If every classical/strong solution to a PDE with boundary values condition is a also a weak solution, then why does Brezis bother with proving the existence of a weak solution to the heat eqution knowing that a classical one exists? (chapter 10). I'm guessing it's due to the initial value $u(x,0)$ belonging to $L^2(\Omega)$ ? while the classical formulation requires it to be continuous everywhere ?

Well maybe there would be no point if you knew there was a classical solution, but you don’t know that. The point is that it’s easier to prove there is a weak solution and to argue that a weak solution must actually be a classical solution (via regularity theory) than to directly prove the existence of a classical solution

@JackT isn't the solution obtained by separation of variables/ fourier method a classical solution ?

@user19645873 Yes but such computing such "simple" solutions is not possible, in general.

The key here is that these methods work for any $\Omega$, whereas classical techniques require specific forms of $\Omega$ to solve the resulting equations
